# Blazor linking error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'input')

Tags: c#, linker, blazor

I have spent some weeks to create a prototype for my customer using the Blazor Webassembly hosting model.  It has worked far above my expectations. Until now. Time for first deployment to real environment on Azure. I have configured PublishTrimmed=true in client and server project files. Is that needed in both projects?

Unfortunately the publish failed on the linking giving me these two errors:

- "Optimizing assemblies for size failed. Optimization can be disabled by setting the PublishTrimmed property to false."
- "IL Linker has encountered an unexpected error. Please report the issue at [https://github.com/mono/linker/issues"](https://github.com/mono/linker/issues%22)

In the dialog I am referred to a tmp file having this content:
"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details."

The output window includes this section:
Fatal error in IL Linker
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'input')
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument arg)
at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(String input)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkTypeWithDebuggerDisplayAttribute(TypeDefinition type, CustomAttribute attribute)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkTypeSpecialCustomAttributes(TypeDefinition type)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference, DependencyInfo reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldDefinition field, DependencyInfo& reason)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireTypeInternal(TypeDefinition type, Boolean includeBaseTypes, DependencyInfo& reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember, HashSet`1 typesAlreadyVisited) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireTypeInternal(TypeDefinition type, Boolean includeBaseTypes, DependencyInfo& reason, IMemberDefinition sourceLocationMember, HashSet`1 typesAlreadyVisited)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)

What can I do? I have really recommended Blazor to my colleagues. I would be ashamed to tell them we need to skip the trimming and publish an application that will give the customers a download size of 9 MB!!!!

Is the trimming just an empty promise or does it actually work in real applications? Can I do something to detect the crucial problem? The error hints are not really helpful. I don't mind reporting an issue, but I have no meaningful details to include in the report.

Comment: You are pointing out so major issues with Blazor WASM: 1) there's a significant download required on startup and 2) it is very new, thus immature. But why is your WASM so big? You should only put the UI in WASM and put all the business logic on a server with API.

Comment: I do have all major logic on server side. The application wasm is reasonable small. But my impression is I also get the complete "framework bundle" of assemblies. ~190 DLL files starting with Microsoft or System. Most of them should not be needed.

Comment: No... weird. Do you have many unnecesary usings in your source? Unnecesary packages? Als [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383353)

Comment: I have optimized my usings. I don't call any services in vain så execution speed is fine. My concern is just the initial load size. I assumed that's where the linker reduction should come in handy. When the linker just fails there obviously is no reduction.