# How to Reduce Loading Time For Blazor Webassembly

Tags: blazor, loading, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a blazor webassembly app

Loading time is more than 30s.

Is this normal?

My temp link: http://chhinsras-001-site1.itempurl.com/

Photo of Downloading: https://sendfile.cc/uploads/file/0.955280001614304830.png

Are there any ways to reduce the size of the app?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Put less stuff in the app. I see a page load has 84 requests, transferring 15 MB. (However, for me it only takes a few s to load... far less then 30s)

Comment: it should be .but i dont know why . so you access my side, it takes you only 2 seconds?

Comment: @Sras the first time I accessed the page, it took a long time to get to the point where any part of the page was loading, including all the referenced resources.  The 2nd time (with a hard refresh even) it was only 2-3 seconds for me.  Is it possible you are using a sort of web host that will put your server to sleep after a while and requires 30 seconds to "wake up" when it gets a new request?

Comment: im not sure. I am hosting on smartasp.net ... waht do you think

Answer (score 11):

Use [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [server side pre rendering](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-wasm-prerendering/)

Read also [ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly performance best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0)